# Problem with "AlertDialog"

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to display an `AlertDialog` but I get an error when I call the `show` function. I use the following code, copied from the `Hello Mapview` code sample :

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
  dialog.setTitle(article.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(article.getSnippet());
  dialog.show();
```

The application crashes when the last line is being executed. I have suspected the `context` variable but it is not guilty because, with it, I can display a `Toast`.

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Comment: If possible please post error log over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second @Brigham.  Make sure the context you pass to your ItemizedOverylay is the activity which displays the MapView. In other words, use something like the following,

```
itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
```

Instead of

```
itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, getApplicationContext());
```

Application context can't be used for AlertDialog, and will result in the following error,

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8679): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Answer (score 0):

You need to call .create() after you create the new AlertDialog.Builder object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess everything will work.. In the below code snippet

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
  dialog.setTitle(article.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(article.getSnippet());
  dialog.show();
```

make this change

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
  dialog.setTitle(article.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(article.getSnippet());
  dialog.show();
```